# Is there a REST API or other means to get crash data from IBM MQA?

Tags: mobile, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'd like to retrieve a log of crashes for my mobile app from IBM Mobile Quality Assurance (MQA) so that I can filter/process these crashes based on certain characteristics.  In particular, I want to excluded crashes that occur in the device simulator since these are most likely happening during automated tests and not actual user crashes.

Is there a REST API or other means to obtain a list of crashes (with details) for my app from IBM MQA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working to improve the MQA filtering features however at this time we don't have a way to filter crashes by devices. We recently announced that MQA in Bluemix now supports integration with the following bug tracking systems: Jira, TFS, HP Quality Center, GitHub, FogBugz.

If you use one of these BTS's, its possible to use their filtering process, if any.

I will speak to the MQA Product Mgr to take this as a future enhancement request.